# Laravel throttle rate limiter limites access too early

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, throttling, rate-limiting

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I wanted to apply a Rate Limiter that limits the sending request to **500 per minute**.

So I tried adding this `throttle` to the route group:

```
Route::middleware('throttle:500,1')->group(function () {
    ...
});
```

So this means that limits access to the routes after 500 requests in 1 minute.

Now the problem is I get **429 | Too Many Requests** too soon!

I mean, it does not seem to be sending 500 requests in a minute but it limits the access somehow.

So what's going wrong here? Why I get Too Many Requests message too early?

Comment: clear your your route cache `php artisan route:clear` and try again

Comment: is this on production? Are you sure you aren't getting 500 requests per minute? (not necessarily from the same source)

Comment: Maybe check the server access logs (set them up if not already set up) to make sure you are not currently being DDoSed or aggressively crawled. As I mentioned the rate limit is global so what other requests are incoming would affect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The throttle middleware requests are calculated together
if you have another throttle group, these calculated together and may that group consume your limits

```
Route::get('example1', function () {
    return 'ans1';

})->middleware('throttle:5,1');

Route::get('example2', function () {
    return 'ans2';

})->middleware('throttle:5,1');
```

In above case, you have 2 route but if you send 2 request to example1  and 3 request to example2, your rate limit will finish for both of them and you got **429 | Too Many Requests** error.

Comment: So do you have any suggestions to fix this case I have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using multiple throttle middlewares in your group and it's nested routes like this:

```php
Route::middleware('throttle:500,1')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/foo', 'bar@foo')->middleware('throttle:5,60');
});
```

the throttle middleware counts each requests twice. for solving this issue,
you must make sure that each route has only one throttle middleware.

But sometimes even though the middleware has been used only once, the request count is still wrong. in that cases, you can make your own customized throttle middleware that takes an extra argument for naming throttle key and prevent re-counting requests (based on [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/28856)).

To do this, you must first create a middleware (according to [this](https://bannister.me/blog/custom-throttle-middleware)):

```php
php artisan make:middleware CustomThrottleMiddleware
```

and then, replace the contents with:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use RuntimeException;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests;

class CustomThrottleMiddleware extends ThrottleRequests
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  int|string  $maxAttempts
     * @param  float|int  $decayMinutes
     * @param  string $keyAppend
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $maxAttempts = 60, $decayMinutes = 1, $keyAppend = '')
    {
        $key = $this->resolveRequestSignature($request, $keyAppend);

        $maxAttempts = $this->resolveMaxAttempts($request, $maxAttempts);

        if ($this->limiter->tooManyAttempts($key, $maxAttempts)) {
            throw $this->buildException($key, $maxAttempts);
        }

        $this->limiter->hit($key, $decayMinutes * 60);

        $response = $next($request);

        return $this->addHeaders(
            $response, $maxAttempts,
            $this->calculateRemainingAttempts($key, $maxAttempts)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Resolve request signature.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string $keyAppend
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    protected function resolveRequestSignature($request, $keyAppend='')
    {
        if ($user = $request->user()) {
            return sha1($user->getAuthIdentifier().$keyAppend);
        }

        if ($route = $request->route()) {
            return sha1($route->getDomain().'|'.$request->ip().$keyAppend);
        }

        throw new RuntimeException('Unable to generate the request signature. Route unavailable.');
    }
}
```

after doing that, you must to register the middleware by updating the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //...
    'custom_throttle' => \App\Http\Middleware\CustomThrottleMiddleware::class,
];
```

now you can use this new customized throttle middleware in your routes, something like this:

```php
Route::middleware('throttle:500,1')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/foo', 'bar@foo')->middleware('custom_throttle:5,60,foo');
});
```